# Embedded ScrollView not working with position absolute in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Reference Code: https://snack.expo.dev/@spk265/courageous-popcorn.

As it can be seen, I am unable to scroll the `ScrollView` element since it has a `position: absolute`. If I remove it, I only see the `ImageBackground` and not the `ScrollView`. How can I make sure the `ScrollView` is scrollable with the `ImageBackground` element as well?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://snack.expo.dev/KveVaWn0W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use absolute for your background and remove absolute from the ScrollView:

```
    <ImageBackground source={IMG} 
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            position: "absolute"
          }}
       />
        <ScrollView style={{
          width: screenWidth,
          minHeight: screenHeight,
          paddingBottom: 100
        }} contentContainerStyle={{
          width: "100%",
          minHeight: "100%",
          justifyContent: "flex-start",
        }}>
```